# Dynamically setting hyperlink's NavigateUrl to a file path does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, download

I am attempting to set a HyperLink control's `NavigateUrl` path to a file, so that the user can click on the link and download the file.  In my C# and ASPX code, the URL appears properly set, but clicking on the link causes nothing to happen; right-clicking on the link and attempting to save the link attempts to save `download.htm`.

Behind the scenes, I'm creating the file in the temp directory and moving it to an available location for download.  This part works; I'm including it for reference.

```
    private string MoveFile(string file_name, string file_path)
    {
        string tempdir = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath( ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["docs_folder"] );
        string new_file_name = Path.Combine( tempdir, Path.GetFileName( file_name ) );
        try
        {
            if (File.Exists( new_file_name ))
            {
                File.Delete( new_file_name );
            }
            File.Move( file_name, new_file_name );
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string message = e.Message;
        }
        return new_file_name;
    }
```

And here's how I'm presently setting the URL:

```
        string download_file = downloader.DownloadFiles(); //Ultimately returns the path from the MoveFile method
        hl_download.NavigateUrl = "file:///" + HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode( download_file ).Replace("\\","//");
        hl_download.Visible = true;
```

My output looks like:
`file:///C://users//codes%20with%20hammer//documents//visual%20studio%202012//Projects//Download%20File//Download%20File//Archive_to_download.zip`

When I drop this URL directly into the browser, the file properly downloads.  So why doesn't it work on the hyperlink?

I also tried setting the property on a static hyperlink.  Same result.  For comparison:
`<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Visible="True" NavigateUrl="file:///C:/users/codes%20with%20hammer/documents/visual%20studio%202012/Projects/Download%20File//Download%20File//Archive_to_download.zip">click me</asp:HyperLink>`

*Revised*

My ASHX page has the following code in `ProcessRequest`:

```
        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        context.Response.AddHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(  download_file ));
        context.Response.WriteFile( context.Server.MapPath( download_file ) );
        context.Response.End();
```

Perhaps I should move this into my code-behind file?

Comment: Do you _really_ want to use `file:///` paths for your hyperlinks? You realize this will only work on the local machine and not for anyone else?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: Good point.  Please suggest something better.  (For what it's worth, the next sprint will push the file to the client, skipping the step of manually downloading it.)

Comment: You can create a `download.aspx` page and pass in a file name/ID/something as part of the query parameters. Then serve the file via [any number of means](https://www.google.ca/webhp#bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=9cd25182cbffae10&q=ASP.NET+file+download+hyperlink). You can also consider setting up a [virtual directory](https://www.google.ca/webhp#bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=9cd25182cbffae10&q=ASP.NET%20virtual%20directory) and link to the files via that. (remember to implement proper security)

Comment: I'm making an ASHX handler page as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725599/asp-net-creating-download-link-to-a-file-on-a-file-server).  How do I pass the file name in the `HttpContext` or the query?

Comment: It's in the very answer you linked: `Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=abc.txt");`

Comment: I'll rephrase my last comment:  How do I pass the file name *to* the ASHX page?  Also, my `WriteFile` needs a virtual directory, not the absolute server path.  I feel very very close to Done on this.

Comment: Pass the file information (file name, path, ID, something else) via the URL query GET parameters.

Answer (score 1):

## Warning - insecure code ahead, do not use. For demo only.

Because you are making an HttpHandler (as per the comments) this is how you would set the NavigateUrl:

```
string download_file = downloader.DownloadFiles(); //Ultimately returns the path from the MoveFile method
hl_download.NavigateUrl = "~/Handler.ashx?file="+download_file; //simply append the path
hl_download.Visible = true;
```

Now, the problem is that the value of `download_file` will be the actual physical path on the server. If you blindly take the value and use it to read the file from your file system, a hacker can use the same technique to download **ANY** file from your server, at least, within your application folder.

**This is somewhat more secure and may be okay to use depending on your scenario**

If you decide to go with the `HttpHandler` option, you are going to have to create some sort of unique token whereby you associate the token to the physical path to the file on  disk. If this is a hyperlink that only needs to be generated once and for the life of the session, you can do something like this:

```
string token = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
Session[token]=download_file; //put the token in the Session dictionary
hl_download.NavigateUrl = "~/Handler.ashx?file="+token;
hl_download.Visible = true;
```

Now, on the `HttpHandler` you can simply do:

```
string file = Session[Request.QueryString["file"]];

if (file!=null)
{
     Response.Clear();
     Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
     Response.AddHeader(string.Format("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename={0}",Path.GetFileName(file)));                                            
     Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath(file));
     Response.End();
}
```

In order to be able to access the Session in your handler, you also have to implement [IReadOnlySessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.ireadonlysessionstate.aspx)

Something like this (full code, **untested**):

```
public class Handler : IHttpHandler, IReadOnlySessionState
{
   public bool IsReusable { get { return true; } }

   public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext ctx)
   {
        string file = ctx.Session[Request.QueryString["file"]];

        if (file!=null)
        {
           Response.Clear();
           Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
           Response.AddHeader(string.Format("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename={0}",Path.GetFileName(file)));                                            
           Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath(file));
           Response.End();
         }
   }
}
```

Of course, the hyperlink is only valid while the Session is still active. If you need to maintain the hyperlink forever, you need to implement this entirely different.

This is more secure because the chances of the token not being unique are very very slim. Also because it only stores the token in the Session, so if *another* user manages to "guess" a token or try a brute-force approach, he still won't get anything since the value simply is not on his Session but on someone else's.

Comment: I've noted your "more secure" approach for the next sprint.  TXVM.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got this to work.  I used a relative path, `./Archive_to_download.zip`.  I have documented the ASHX method for the next sprint.

Answer (score 0):

```
 lb.NavigateUrl = "~/Picture/" + files[i].Name;
```