# Navigation error

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, apk

I have a hyperlink button in my Silverlight 4 application. I want to download an `apk` file when I click on this link. I am able to download file but my problem is that when I click on link it downloads the file and trie to navigate on that link so it shows the dialog for file download and raises an exception.

[image]

and the code behind hyperlink button is

```
    private void hyperlinkButton1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       Uri myAbsoluteUri = new Uri(Application.Current.Host.Source,"../download/ItimHRMSAndroidApp.apk");
       HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(myAbsoluteUri);

    }
```

I just want to open the download link - not actually navigating to that page.

Comment: Try setting the target parameter to '_blank' so it opens a new window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the URI within the markup:

```
<HyperlinkButton x:Name="MyButton" TargetName="_blank" Content="Download APK" NavigateUri="/download/ItimHRMSAndroidApp.apk" Canvas.Top="40" Canvas.Left="30"></HyperlinkButton>
```

And remove the `Click` event handler:

```
 private void hyperlinkButton1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     Uri myAbsoluteUri = new Uri(Application.Current.Host.Source,"../download/ItimHRMSAndroidApp.apk");
     HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(myAbsoluteUri);
 }
```

Comment: where does this download folder be? In silverlight project.? how to point towards the website download folder?

Comment: The `download` folder will be in the root of your website hosting your Silverlight app. e.g. if your website is `www.example.com` this will point to `http://www.example.com/download/ItimHRMSAndroidApp.apk`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try using a [Generic Web handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

And return the apk file
[Like this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725599/creating-download-link-to-a-file-on-a-file-server)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was not of the _target field. it is of the path.

Comment: yes buddy. your answer was helpful too. i accepted your answer as correct answer.