# Issue downloading excel file using anchor tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, download

I make HTML on runtime , and this is one of the lines:

```
<a target=\"_blank\" href=\""+filepath+"\">Download</a>
```

Where `filepath` is like `F:\Website\Files\records.xlsx`

The issue the the above opens a new tab with the file path in it but nothing happens the browser says the address was not understood. However when i click the address and press enter i see the download popup and can't seem to find out the issue.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Already answered here : [Answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725599/creating-download-link-to-a-file-on-a-file-server?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

> Where filepath is like F:\Website\Files\records.xlsx

How should a "local path" work on a website (I assume you are not targeting an intranet, where `F:\` is a shared drive for everyone. If so please update the question adding that info)?

You possible want something like:

```
string filepath = "records.xlsx";
string anchor = "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"/Files/" + filepath + "\">Download</a>";
```

And under the URL `/Files/....` you map a file handler which sends the file to the client. If you tell us what technology you are using (WebForms, MVC, ...) I can give you an example how to do this...

Comment: This site will be on a VPS so the path will work fine.Am i not suppose to put the complete path to the download file? As is said the path works fine when i press enter on it again. It seems the download popup does not come up only the first time .

Comment: @confusedMind: I guess it works fine on your local machine, because there `F:\Website\Files\records.xlsx` exist, but for example if I would click that link (or enter a second time) it would NOT work, as I do not even have a drive `F:`. Tell us what technology you are using and I can give you a complete example...

Comment: This link comes from a DB , and is saved using the Server.MapPath to the file locations so i am assuming it will work. I am using asp.net c# . Also solved it using :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725599/creating-download-link-to-a-file-on-a-file-server?rq=1