# How to give URL for a file stored in app_data folder in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a zip file stored in app_data folder .I want to give the path ofthat  file as URL for a hyperlink.How to assign it
Server.Mappath(~/App_Data/Test.zip) will give the physical location as D:/Projects/Mnv/App_Data/Test.zip , but i want to give it as URL like http://..../test.zip, so user can download

Comment: Return the Result back as a file via your controller rather than giving direct access to the file itself, if you can.

Comment: look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725599/creating-download-link-to-a-file-on-a-file-server

Comment: @Code Rider that worked,but extension is coming as .ashx instead of .zip,how to correct it

Comment: @Code Ride if the file is .kmz ,what will be response.contenttype here??

Comment: I got that is the correct answer thanks Code rider

Answer (score 2):

You should not use App_Data available to the users.

This is a special folder used to store internal data only (XML, sdf, etc..).

By default, this folder is not even available via Http.

Yo can create an Action in your Asp.Net MVC and use it to retun some file from this folder. A direct download, however, it is not recommended.